# How to maintain lightning experience for mobile devices?

Tags: lightning, community, salesforce1-app, lightning-experience

Is their any way to maintain lightning experience for mobile devices? currently on mobile devices Salesforce1 version being getting rendered.

I tried by disabling below option but then for mobile devices site runs in classic mode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce app (previously known as Salesforce 1) always has a different and its own mobile experience and it does not inherit its look and feel from either Classic or Lightning Experience.

Lightning Experience is meant to run on desktop browsers and is not extended to Mobile devices. However components built using Lightning Component framework are mobile compatible and they can be rendered on any platform with no/minimal changes.

You can find more on this [knowledge documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194219&type=1), excerpt below:

> **Which mobile experiences are supported by Salesforce?**
>
> Salesforce for Android & iOS is the only UI supported by Salesforce for mobile devices. Salesforce for Android & iOS is available either via mobile web browser (as a mobile web experience) or as a mobile app, which can be downloaded from the App Store for iOS devices or Google Play for Android devices.

Also refer to the below excerpt from [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_whatis):

> That’s why Lightning Experience takes the cool stuff from the Salesforce mobile experience and brings it to the desktop.

Comment: hello Jayant, Thanks for your inputs. My application also has some custom components but those are not getting render in Salesforce1. Do we have any solution for the same?

Comment: Lightning Components are mobile ready. If those are not getting rendered, you may like to review your code as to see what is the root cause which is causing it not to be rendered on mobile devices.

Comment: I mean, lightning components are getting render, but there are some custom components and layout that is missing in mobile version.

It seems Salesforce1 is only considering lightning components and runs everything in default layout.  right ?

Comment: Didn't quite follow, but anything that is compatible will be rendered on mobile. So if you have a custom lightning component, it will be rendered. But if you have something that's not supported on that layout, it won't or it will be rendered however the mobile container renders it.